# Optional capture group part

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex pattern:

```
[^-]+-(.+)[^\d](.+)-(.*?)-.*(\d+).*-([\w]+-[\w]+-[^-]+)-(\d+-\d+)-(.+)\.
```

That needs to match both these cases

```
Data Location 1 - many many words 201808206566 - many words - 010114-INL-USD-B087834-2018-08-Bill.PDF

Data Location 1 - many many words 201808206565 - many words - 010115-INL-B087845-2018-08-Bill.PDF
```

As is, this matches the first case and not the second. And I get the opposite result by removing one instance of `[\w]+-` from within the 5th capture group, this is because the first case contains INL-USD-B087834, which has an additional data block in it. How can I make the second instance optional?

Comment: BTW, you can just write `\w+` instead of `[\w]+`

Comment: What are you trying to pull from this `exactly`.  It may be better to create a simpler Regex to pull what you need then to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an optional group using the `?` operator.

```
[^-]+-(.+)[^\d](.+)-(.*?)-.*(\d+).*-(\w+-(?:\w+-)?[^-]+)-(\d+-\d+)-(.+)\.
```

Or you use a numeric quantifier to allow 1 or 2 word blocks there:

```
[^-]+-(.+)[^\d](.+)-(.*?)-.*(\d+).*-((?:\w+-){1,2}[^-]+)-(\d+-\d+)-(.+)\.
```

Comment: Your patterns cause catastrophical backtracking with the top example, see https://regex101.com/r/TQCOm2/1

Comment: The OP's pattern has the same problem. I couldn't figure out how to fix it, so I just posted my answer with the change necessary to answer the question.